# How to split multiple strings of data into html table

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

So we have data in our DB that is looks like this in 1 column

Example Data: 86, 50, 21, 411, 83, 60, 0, 112, 47, 118.5, 1.31, 3.79, 2.3, 70, 401, 125

I want to split this data at every , and for it to go into a table like so.

Example:
[image]

the problem is I cannot seem to find a way to do this on Powerapps or PowerAutomate.

Any help would be greatly apprecaited!

I have tried using Mid previously but because not every line is the same length that could not be possible.

Ideally I want to be able to split but not just the first or last.

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-split) and [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-concatenate) functions to create the table with the values. For example, you can set this expression in the HtmlText property of a HTML Text control:

```
With(
    {
        Headers: Split("Power,Freq,Comp Intake,Exhaust,Eng Fresh Water,RW IN,RW OUT,Oil Sump,Inlet Manifold,Fuel Use,Boost,Engine Oil Press,Smoke,Blow by,Voltage,Current", ","),
        Units: Split("KWe,Hz,ºC,ºC,ºC,ºC,ºC,ºC,ºC,mm3/ST,Bar,Bar,FSN,L/min,volts,amps", ","),
        Values: Split("86, 50, 21, 411, 83, 60, 0, 112, 47, 118.5, 1.31, 3.79, 2.3, 70, 401, 125", ",")
    },
    "<table border='1'>" &
        "<tr>" & Concat(Headers, "<th>" & Result & "</th>") & "</tr>" &
        "<tr>" & Concat(Units, "<th>" & Result & "</th>") & "</tr>" &
        "<tr>" & Concat(Values, "<td align='middle'>" & Result & "</td>") & "</tr>" &
        "</table>")
```

[image: Table with single line of values]

If you have multiple rows of data, you can also use the [Concat function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-concatenate) to merge them together into rows, something along the lines of the expression below:

```
With(
    {
        Headers: Split("Power,Freq,Comp Intake,Exhaust,Eng Fresh Water,RW IN,RW OUT,Oil Sump,Inlet Manifold,Fuel Use,Boost,Engine Oil Press,Smoke,Blow by,Voltage,Current", ","),
        Units: Split("KWe,Hz,ºC,ºC,ºC,ºC,ºC,ºC,ºC,mm3/ST,Bar,Bar,FSN,L/min,volts,amps", ","),
        Measurements: [
            "86, 50, 21, 411, 83, 60, 0, 112, 47, 118.5, 1.31, 3.79, 2.3, 70, 401, 125",
            "86, 50, 23, 416, 83, 60, 0, 113, 49, 117.3, 1.31, 3.76, 2.4, 65, 400, 124",
            "95, 50, 23, 436, 84, 60, 0, 115, 51, 131.3, 1.45, 3.69, 2.8, 65, 400, 136",
            "65, 50, 22, 389, 82, 60, 0, 112, 50, 92.8, .97, 3.76, 2.2, 60, 401, 93",
            "43, 50, 21, 332, 81, 60, 0, 104, 47, 63.3, .62, 3.86, .8, 50, 402, 62",
            "22, 50, 21, 237, 80, 60, 0, 101, 46, 35.3, . ZS, 4, .8, 40, 402, 32",
            "00, 50, 21, 122, 79, 60, 0, 95, 44, 11.7, .14, 4.14, .1, 35, 402, 0"
        ]
    },
    "<table border='1'>" &
        "<tr>" & Concat(Headers, "<th>" & Result & "</th>") & "</tr>" &
        "<tr>" & Concat(Units, "<th>" & Result & "</th>") & "</tr>" &
        Concat(
            Measurements,
            "<tr>" & Concat(Split(Value, ","), "<td align='middle'>" & Result & "</td>") & "</tr>"
        ) &
        "</table>")
```

[image: Table with multiple lines of values]

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! 

One of the other challenges I am having is that I could have 4 or 7 rows of data, so I am not sure how to pass that through either.

Example: https://imgur.com/a/OaTdzgF

Comment: Updated the answer with how to use multiple rows.

Comment: Thank you again Carlos! This is immensely helpful! and very much appreciated!

I have one issue left and have included a screen shot again to hopefully better explain.
Example: https://imgur.com/a/Da39qlk

So I basically want to split it twice I think (there could be a better way) where I want to split on the "," for the individual data but I also need it to start a new line as well.

As you can see from the example image, it all stacks onto the first row. Any help would be massively appreciated as this is the last part I am missing! Thank you again!